# batch equivalent of shell for output of command

Tags: shell, batch-file

Shell command:

```
export My_VAL=`cd shell && my-cli preview | sed -n '2 p'`
```

Command above:

1. cd to shell folder
2. runs "my-cli preview" command
3. gets the second line of command line output
4. stores it in MY_VAL

What would be it's equivalent windows/batch command?

Comment: The `FOR` command with the `/F` option is used to capture output of other commands. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('myprogram.exe') DO set "var=%%G"`. The `CD` command would be on its own line before the `FOR` command.

Comment: your solution save last line of output, not a second one.

Comment: @user2956477, it was just an example of how to capture output.  Hence why I put a pseudo executable name.  When a user makes no attempt at solving the problem themselves they get an example.  We are not hear to write code from scratch or translate code from one language to another for a user when they make no valid attempt at doing it themselves. Teach a man to fish.  Don't give them the fish.

Comment: Than you should mark your code as an example only, or someone could be confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "MY_VAL="
cd shell
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('my_cli preview') do if "!MY_VAL!"=="" set "MY_VAL=%%a"
```

Comment: I get `%%a was unexpected at this time.`. And nothing is stored in MY_VAL

Comment: are you traying it from script file, or directly in console window?

Comment: If you used `IF NOT DEFINED MY_VAL` you would not need to use delayed expansion.  I would also consider using a `GOTO` to break out of the `FOR` command once `MY_VAL` has been assigned a value.

Comment: would MY_VAL be an environment variable?

After the script runs, if I try `echo %MY_VAL%, I get nothing.

Comment: @raneshu because of the `SETLOCAL` an implicit `ENDLOCAL` executes when the batch file is done executing.  You have two options. 1) Follow my advice in my previous comment. 2) To fix the existing code use this as your last line: `endlocal & set "my_val=%my_val%"`.